# use android prefix on xml (android:, app:, @.., ...)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

On AndroidStudio in xml file i don't understand the difference between item with android prefix and item without it
part of my source code for example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

in this xml file why some attributes want the prefix (android:) and other not.
for the example:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

this part of code works correctly, but when the code below is used, it doesn't works:
    `<item name="textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>`
So can anyone help me to know the difference between the prefix, and when i use it. thanks

Comment: Also discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845565/what-is-android-prefix-mean-in-android-framework-res-module

Answer (score 1):

That is because some of those attributes are from a different XML name space.
In layout files, you may have seen something like:

```
<Linear Layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

You need a way to tell the compiler that you will be referencing attributes from that location, and you do that with the

```
"android:"
```